# Missing Basic References

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-2.0

After copying my project from 1 computer to another. I got this problem where visual studio is telling me I'm missing references.

```
Import of type 'System.Data.DataSet' from assembly or module '<unknown>' failed
Import of type 'System.Drawing.Color' from assembly or module '<unknown>' failed
```

there a few more references missing but I'm assuming it's all part of the same problem.

**Things I've tried:**

- ensuring the project is building with .net 2.0
- ensuring the path exists to the reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you're saying that the appropriate references actually do exist in the project properties?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove the references and add them again?

You can also try setting the references `'Copy Local'` Property to `True` and build it on the original computer, and only then copy the project and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the libraries you're missing manually. Try to add a reference to System.Drawing for example. I know this is not optimal, but if you're stressed for time (aka a project you need to submit) then it might work.

Comment: What do you mean manually? I've added the reference to System.data and it should contain system.data.dataset.